# Laravel Query Builder MIN method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, min

I've this code below (Laravel 5 Query Builder), that should return the list of the posts having the id under the specified id and the minimum id founded.

As you can see the query use the take in order to limit the result, the value passed is an integer.

The problem is that the postList variable contain correctly the requested values but the firstPostID return the minumum founded in the db and not the minumum that the query i'm expecting to obtain.

```
$q = DB::table('posts')
            ->select('posts.id', 'posts.title', 'posts.created_at', 'users.name AS creatorName')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.creatorid_ext')
                ->take(Config::get('generals.history_posts_number'))
                ->where('posts.id', '<', $id)->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc');



        $postsList   = $q->get();

        $firstPostID = $q->min('posts.id');
```

This is what i get

```html
{
   "firstid": 1,
   "posts": [
      {
         "created_at": "2015-03-01 12:00:00",
         "creatorName": "XXXX",
         "id": 6,
         "title": "this is the sixth title"
      },
      {
         "created_at": "2015-03-01 11:00:00",
         "creatorName": "XXX",
         "id": 5,
         "title": "this is the fifth title"
      },
      {
         "created_at": "2015-03-01 10:00:00",
         "creatorName": "XXX",
         "id": 4,
         "title": "this is the fourth title"
      },
      {
         "created_at": "2015-03-01 09:00:00",
         "creatorName": "XXX",
         "id": 3,
         "title": "this is the tirhd title"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is what i want to get

```html
{
   "firstid": 3,
   "posts": [
      {
         "created_at": "2015-03-01 12:00:00",
         "creatorName": "XXX",
         "id": 6,
         "title": "this is the sixth title"
      },
      {
         "created_at": "2015-03-01 11:00:00",
         "creatorName": "XXX",
         "id": 5,
         "title": "this is the fifth title"
      },
      {
         "created_at": "2015-03-01 10:00:00",
         "creatorName": "XXX",
         "id": 4,
         "title": "this is the fourth title"
      },
      {
         "created_at": "2015-03-01 09:00:00",
         "creatorName": "XXX",
         "id": 3,
         "title": "this is the tirhd title"
      }
   ]
}
```

Many Thanks for your help